# Process JSON with key name containing brackets

Tags: json, jq

I have the following JSON

```
{
    "jps": {
      "onInstall": [{
        "cmd [sqldb]": [
            "command"
        ]
      }]
    }
  }
```

Without `[sqldb]`, I was doing the query as follows:

```
jq '.jps.onInstall.cmd=["long line", "another line"]' my-app.json
```

And it worked, but with `[sqldb]`, how can I translate it to jq query format?

I tried

`jps.onInstall.cmd\[sqldb\]` and `jps.onInstall.cmd.sqldb` but no luck

Comment: `.jps.onInstall.cmd=["long line", "another line"]` that can't have worked given your JSON input in question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not with the special character `"cmd [sqldb]"` but with your `onInstall` type, which is a list type, but you are missing the `.[]` indicator

```
.jps.onInstall[]."cmd [sqldb]" = ["long line", "another line"]
```

or

```
.jps.onInstall[]["cmd [sqldb]"] = ["long line", "another line"]
```

Comment: It does not work, `.jps.onInstall[]."cmd [sqldb]"=["a"]` resulted in `"jps": { "onInstall": [] } }`

Comment: @Rodrigo: Please see https://jqplay.org/s/3utNVpaV1zo, containing the JSON you posted above. If not update your JSON in the question to the one you are using locally